# Code for searching in a String if it contains a Char[] array?

Tags: java, android, arabic

I'm developing an app that has a feature to search a text (`searchString` ) in Arabic language if it is in a .txt file (.txt file is also in Arabic language).

Since Android doesn't support Arabic 100%, `String.indexof()` doesn't work properly. So, I thought, I would put the `searchString` into a `Char[]` array and instead of comparing the whole word, I compare every character. So I put the `searchString` into a `char[]` and start comparing the array to the String

Is it available anywhere a code that searches if the sequence that is in the char[] array is into a String?

example:

```
char[]={t,e,s,t}  String1{qqwtestq} String2{qwqtqwe}  -> String1:TRUE   String2:FALSE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` and `contains` don't use character encoding of any sort and you can use characters which are not used in your character encoding for example. i.e. it is ignored for these functions.

All String.indexOf() and contains do is compare character for character.  I am not sure what behaviour you are expecting for 100% Arabic support.  Here is a simplified version what the indexOf()/contains() does

```
public static int indexOf(String string, char[] chars) {
    LOOP:
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length() - chars.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++)
            if (string.charAt(i + j) != chars[j])
                continue LOOP;
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    char[] chars = "test".toCharArray();
    String one = "qqwtestq";
    String two = "qwqtqwe";
    String str = new String(chars);
    System.out.println("indexOf(" + one+", " + Arrays.toString(chars) + ") = " + indexOf(one, chars));
    System.out.println(one + ".indexOf(" + str + ") = " + one.indexOf(str));
    System.out.println("indexOf(" + two+", " + Arrays.toString(chars) + ") = " + indexOf(two, chars));
    System.out.println(two + ".indexOf(" + str + ") = " + two.indexOf(str));

    char[] chars2 = { '\uffff', '\uFeFF' };
    String test = "qqw\uffff\uFeFFq";
    String str2 = new String(chars2);
    System.out.println("indexOf(" + test+", " + Arrays.toString(chars2) + ") = " + indexOf(test, chars2));
    System.out.println(test + ".indexOf(" + str2 + ") = " + test.indexOf(str2));
}
```

Prints

```
indexOf(qqwtestq, [t, e, s, t]) = 3
qqwtestq.indexOf(test) = 3
indexOf(qwqtqwe, [t, e, s, t]) = -1
qwqtqwe.indexOf(test) = -1
indexOf(qqw??q, [?, ?]) = 3
qqw??q.indexOf(??) = 3
```

Can you provide an example where this method doesn't work?

EDIT: This test checks every possible character to see if indexOf behaves as expected. i.e. the same for every possible character.

```
for(int i=Character.MIN_VALUE;i<= Character.MAX_VALUE;i++) {
    String find = new String(new char[] {(char) i});
    String str = new String(new char[] {(char) (i+1), (char) i});
    String str1 = new String(new char[] {(char) (i+1)});

    int test1 = str.indexOf(find);
    if (test1 != 1)
        throw new AssertionError("test1 failed i="+i);

    int test2 = str1.indexOf(find);
    if (test2 != -1)
        throw new AssertionError("test2 failed i="+i);
}
```

Finds no discrepancies.

Comment: This is the worst time complexity you can get from a string searching algorithm. I also don't think searching for a char[] will solve the character encoding problem.

Comment: @Ioan, its basically the same as the one Oracle's Java uses. Can you suggest another, more efficient approach?

Comment: Well the indexof() worked in the emulator, which doesnt support Arabic properly (Arabic language is made of characters that are connected each other, and Android shows the characters, but doesnt connect them) while they didnt work on my phone so I though there was a connection between indexof and the lack of Arabic support.

Comment: This may not won't work if it turns a single character into multiple char's.  However, I would suggest you either a) use an encoding where each character is one char. b) use a comparision which understands the rules of how it turns each character into multiple characters.

Comment: Can you please explain "a) use an encoding where each character is one char." .. how can i specify which encoding to use? i would use utf8

Comment: You state that "Arabic language is made of characters that are connected each other".  I am not sure why this would be the case, however UTF-8 assumes there are only characters, not "connected characters"  I guess this is your problem.  Is there a character encoding such that all "connected characters" have their own unique character?

Comment: @Omar The java char type is a size of 2 bytes (it ranges from 0 to ffff). Some languages such as japanese or Chinese have characters with code points larger than ffff and thus need more than 2 bytes. Than means that in order to store a Chinese character you need to encode it in UTF-16 and use two chars. For utf8 encoding you should use a byte[] instead of a char[]. utf8 uses from 1 to 4 bytes for storing any any character. I recommend you read this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html . It's really really good.

Comment: The way UTF-16 is arranged in Java, indexOf() still works, but it gives you the index of the encoded character (rather than the character number)  I don't believe this applies to Arabic characters.

Answer (score 1):

Implement KMP!
 http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

**EDIT**
Sorry, I did not know about Arabic on Android. Some [suggestions](http://www.vrami.net/?p=635) point to [Cyanogen](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/86241.aspx), and that only Android 3.0 supports Arabic.

Comment: As the others said I think that the problem isnt in searching but in encoding :S

Answer (score 0):

Try [StringUtils](http://www.jdocs.com/lang/2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) contains method.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    char[] ch = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };

    String string1 = "qqwtestq";
    if (string1.contains((new StringBuffer()).append(ch)))
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("false");
```

Comment: +0: contains just calls indexOf()

Comment: As I said above, I dont want to use indexOf since (I GUESS) it doesnt go well with Arabic words for the lack of proper support. What I want to compare each character alone.. I know that that would require more resources but I cant do anything about it

Comment: @Omar, indexOf/contains compares each character alone. See my answer.